# Identifying SMD component on Philips TV 65OLED804/12 remote control

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

I need to know what kind of SMD this is. The text on it says: VUAI, and the device is the Philips remote control YKF463-001.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly a TI Step Up converter [TLV61220](https://www.ti.com/product/TLV61220/part-details/TLV61220DBVR).  It matches both the designator, and the extra marking shown on the pictures of the part from LCSC's  [website](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/DC-DC-Converters_Texas-Instruments-TLV61220DBVR_C111811.html) (link provided by nanash1 in the comments).

Very commonly used to provide a stable, logic supply from dry cells.  This identification also fits with the surrounding components, and the apparent connection to the battery terminals.

Comment: [LCSC](https://www.lcsc.com) has pictures of most TI parts and also [this one](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/DC-DC-Converters_Texas-Instruments-TLV61220DBVR_C111811.html). It's a good source to confirm you found the right part, so you don't have be vague in your answer.

Comment: I had looked at a photo, and was confident it was the part in question, but always tend to a cautious position.  I will tweak my comment to express a higher degree of certainty, and include your link

Comment: thank you all for your helping. Almost very sure that I got the correct component.